# visual studio C++ header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, header-files

Visual Studio is not recognising my `#include 'Header.h'` file. I have created the file in the Header Files in solution explorer and also tried manually pointing to the file. What I don't understand is, until yesterday there was absolutely no problem. Therefore, a simple cout doesn't work.

```
#include 'Header.h';

int main()
{
    cout << "hi";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is in `Header.h`? Unless it has `#include <iostream>` and `using std:cout;`, this won't work. Also, don't put semi-colons after pre-processor directives.

Comment: Could you please mention the "Header.h" contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "hi";

    return 0;
}
```

Not that `Header.h` is used in anyway, this is still the correct syntax.
You need `#include <iostream>` to be able to use `cout`.

Comment: Thanks but, adding <iostream> which is already in my header file seems like a repeat. Also, any ideas why it may have been working yesterday but not today?

Comment: There is no way that i could have figured out what was in your header file from what you posted as your question. You should really skip the header file and just go with `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 2):

You've got syntax errors in your #include preprocessor directive. Replace single with double quotes and drop the semicolon:

```
#include "Header.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem : I had to go to properties bar and change "Included In Folder" value to true from false.